# Collision with supposedly aligned box-colliders

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, collider

I am quite new to game development, and I am trying to create a top-down game with 2D sprites, but with a 3D feel to it. I managed to do so with the 2D engine by setting `Transparency Sort Mode` to `Custom Axis` with the axis values set to `(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)`. I then moved the pivot of GameObjects to bottom-center and used the pivot as sorting point for the sprites. I am now trying to create the environment, but my character 'clips' against the Box Colliders, even though I did all I could think of to align them (same pivot coordinates, same collider offset and size). See the attached GIF for an example:

[image]

I think that the cause is mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/collision-issues-when-using-2d-box-colliders?_ga=2.60152557.1394478133.1600536235-1224716786.1600536235), but there are no solutions mentioned there. My two solutions:

- Remove the colliders, group the objects in a parent object, and add the collider there. But then I would get the same issue if I place two of those instances next to each other.
- I am still pondering to drop this approach altogether and try the same in the 3D engine, but with a fixed camera angle. I lack experience to estimate if that would be a better approach, so if someone thinks that approach would be better suited to this game style, I am happy to hear it.

Can anyone give me advice on this issue, or point me towards resources that might be useful?

Thanks in advance,

Florian

---

Some pictures of the settings I used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to use a [TilemapCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TilemapCollider2D.html) and/or [CompositeCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CompositeCollider2D.html) to merge and erase edges between tiles?

Comment: I did try to add a `CompositeCollider2D` to the parent, and check 'Used by Composite' on the children's `BoxCollider2D`'s. This did not solve the issue. Should I tweak any other settings for that to work? Also; you mention 'between tiles'. Not sure if it matters, but maybe good to add that although the floor is a `TileMap` in a `Grid`, my `GameObjects` are not aligned to a grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113301/discussion-between-florian-and-dmgregory).

Answer (score 1):

DMGregory asked me some other good questions in the comments that made me think about my problem. Based on that, I was able to solve the problem myself. In the end, I solved it by using the proposed `CompositeCollider2D`, and by toggling `Grid Snapping` on.

[image]

I then aligned the objects while snapping to the grid, and this seems to have resolved the 'clipping'.

However, the clipping now occured at the edge of the wall. In addition, I had to set the `BoxCollider2D` on the `Player`, to a `CapsuleCollider2D`.